# SQL : how to pass arguments to custom functions when they contain '\'

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column of type text and it is called user_name. The rest is not important for this discussion.

I have a custom function, called findme and it takes one text argument

I have 3 rows in this table:

user_name
joe
[unknown]
domain\username

so the query is :

```
findme((''[unknown]'' = user_name)) returns one row
findme((''domain\\username'' = user_name)) does not return any rows
```

What is incorrect about the second query and the way I am passing the argument to the function?

Comment: Show us your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I only needed one . I am using Postgres 9.1